View on a history table - question how implement a view on history table
question about creating a view with history table.
I've got a table that i moved old rows to history table,
now i would like to delete the data from the main table.
Main table : Currency.InstrumentRates
History table : History.InstrumentRates
My question is :
Can i create a view with the name of the table Currency.InstrumentRates
after changing main table to : Currency.InstrumentRates_main
so that the change will be transparent to the client side?
here is the new view i want to use:
CREATE VIEW [Currency].[InstrumentRates]
AS
    SELECT  Id,InstrId,ARate,BRate,RateProviderId,DateFrom,DateTo
    FROM    [Currency].[InstrumentRates_main] WITH(NOLOCK)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  Id,InstrId,ARate,BRate,RateProviderId,DateFrom,DateTo
    FROM    [History].[InstrumentRates] WITH(NOLOCK)

GO

so the deployent will be :

transfer old data to history table
delete old data from main table
change table name to : [Currency].[InstrumentRates_main]
create view named : [Currency].[InstrumentRates]

i want to know if the insert and update will still work with the view
and will it insert to [Currency].[InstrumentRates_main]

there is no Update on this table only Insert.
also from my understanding as this table has a high transaction rate (many inserts per seconds) a Temporal table is ill advice for this kind of table.
which reminds me i have this error from a different table which is a Temporal table.
error:
Data modification failed on system-versioned table 'FiatDB.Fiat.Balances' because transaction time was earlier than period start time for affected records.


Can i create a view with the name of the table Currency.InstrumentRates after changing main table to : Currency.InstrumentRates_main so that the change will be transparent to the client side?

Yes.

so the deployent will be :

transfer old data to history table
delete old data from main table
change table name to : [Currency].[InstrumentRates_main]
create view named : [Currency].[InstrumentRates]


Yup, that makes sense.

i want to know if the insert and update will still work with the view and will it insert to [Currency].[InstrumentRates_main]

Unfortunately not directly if you plan to UNION / UNION ALL the history table into the view, as outlined in the Updatable Views docs:

You can modify the data of an underlying base table through a view, as long as the following conditions are true:

...The columns cannot be derived in any other way, such as through the following:

A computation. The column cannot be computed from an expression that uses other columns. Columns that are formed by using the set operators UNION, UNION ALL, CROSSJOIN, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT amount to a computation and are also not updatable.




Luckily there's a solution with triggers, as per the docs again:

If the previous restrictions prevent you from modifying data directly through a view, consider the following options:

INSTEAD OF Triggers
INSTEAD OF triggers can be created on a view to make a view updatable. The INSTEAD OF trigger is executed instead of the data modification statement on which the trigger is defined. This trigger lets the user specify the set of actions that must happen to process the data modification statement. Therefore, if an INSTEAD OF trigger exists for a view on a specific data modification statement (INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE), the corresponding view is updatable through that statement. For more information about INSTEAD OF triggers, see DML Triggers.




hi J.D
thanks for the reply.
as the only way to insert data is by a procedure,
i plan on altering the procedure so it insert to the new table,
and by that avoiding Trigger.
